# Issue in acceptance test while redirecting to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I am writing an acceptance test to check on clicking a button it gets redirected to another page(carts page), but I am getting an error while trying to do the same.

my code is:-

`gift_cards_controller.rb`

```
class GiftCardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_order_and_shipment, only: [:create]

  def create
    super do |format|
      if resource.errors.messages.any?
        format.html { render :new }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to carts_path }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

acceptance spec :-

`gift_card_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe 'Gift Card', type: :feature do
  before(:all) do
    Address.delete_all
  end

  it 'redirects to cart page' do
    user    = create(:user)
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
    address = create(:address, name: 'ABC',
                      street: 'PQR',
                      postal_code: '12345',
                      state_or_region: 'XYZ',
                      phone_number: '123-456-7890',
                      city: 'LMN',
                      user: user)

    add_str = 'ABC, PQR, LMN, XYZ, 12345'
    visit new_gift_card_path
    page.should_not have_content('Please add address before creating a gift card')
    page.should have_button('create gift card')
    fill_in 'gift_card_name',    with: 'Gift Card'
    fill_in 'gift_card_value',   with: 1000.99
    fill_in 'gift_card_message', with: "This is A Gift Card"
    option = first('#gift_card_address_list option').text
    expect(option).to eq(add_str)

    click_button 'create gift card'
    expect(page.current_url).to eq(carts_url)
    page.should have_content('ORDER SUMMARY')
  end
end
```

error:-

```
Gift Card
  redirects to cart page (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Gift Card redirects to cart page
     Failure/Error: expect(page.current_url).to eq(carts_url)

       expected: "http://www.example.com/cart"
            got: "http://www.example.com/gift_cards/new?gift_card[code]=75C4FC&gift_card[name]=Gift+Card&gift_card[value]=1000.99&gift_card[message]=This+is+A+Gift+Card&commit=create+gift+card"
```

[Edit]

On execution of `click_button 'create gift card'` line in the rspec, the control does not enter the create method in the controller. Because of which I am unable to check  `resourse.errors.messages.any?`

`view/gift_cards/new.html.haml`

```
#giftcard
  .giftCard
    %h1
      Create A Gift Card

    = simple_form_for :gift_card, url: gift_cards_path, method: :post do |f|
      %form
        %fieldset
          .form-inputs
            = f.input :code,input_html: {value: GiftCard.generate_code}, required: true
            = f.input :name,  label: 'Gift Card Name/Caption', required: false
            = f.input :value, label: 'Amount'
            = f.input :address_list, collection: current_user.addresses,
              label_method: :get_address_string, include_blank: false
            = f.input :message, as: :text, required: false
            = f.button :submit, 'create gift card',
              class: 'gift_card_submit', disable_with: "creating your gift card..."
```

`routes.rb`

> resources :gift_cards

```
 gift_cards_path      GET      /gift_cards(.:format)                gift_cards#index
                         POST     /gift_cards(.:format)             gift_cards#create
    new_gift_card_path   GET      /gift_cards/new(.:format)         gift_cards#new
    edit_gift_card_path  GET      /gift_cards/:id/edit(.:format)    gift_cards#edit
    gift_card_path       GET      /gift_cards/:id(.:format)         gift_cards#show
                         PUT      /gift_cards/:id(.:format)         gift_cards#update
                         DELETE   /gift_cards/:id(.:format)         gift_cards#destroy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your form is incorrect.

```
= simple_form_for :gift_card, url: gift_cards_path, method: :post do |f|
  %form
    %fieldset
      .form-inputs
```

1. remove the `%form` element
2. Use REST convention `simple_form_for @gift_card do |f|`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the controller code you shared, it appears that either it's failing your `before_filter` or `resource.errors.messages.any?` was truthy and you rendered the `new` view rather than redirecting to `carts_path`. Without any other code, there's not much else to tell.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Peter. which part of the code you want me to add?

Comment: you should find out why validation is failed here (what is the error message here `resource.errors.messages.any?`) and change your test to build a valid resource.

Comment: @gotva I have edited the question. As mentioned above, I am unable to view the errors as the control does not enter the create method of the controller. You have any other suggestions? Do let me know, thanks

Comment: Ok. Is it getting to your `before_filter`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin no, it's not getting in before_filter.

Comment: Ok, then I'd check your view and your routes to make sure they collective map to your create method.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I have added view and routes in question.

Comment: Sorry, this is not my area of expertise. The only other thing I can think of is to post the resulting HTML (e.g. as available through `page.html in your test`) and/or post whatever is getting logged to your console in the way of HTTP traffic (i.e. methods, params). What I'm puzzled by is the fact that there is a `/new` in the "got" URL along with the values of the parameters your test filled in, suggesting that _something_ got submitted, but it didn't go to the path you specified (which doesn't have the `/new`) or got redirected.